# Receive the InputStream and get the values from json string in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, inputstream

How can I received JSON string from the `InputStream` in Jersey, which was sent from `HttpURlConenction` in android, and how can I get the values of it to store them into  database table?

```
{
 "latitude":93.86898451,
  "longitude":30.66561387,
  "time":"24.04.2015 11:11:05",
  "route":4
}
```

Jersey receiver class:

```
@Path("data")
public class Receiver {



    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
    public void storeDate() {
        BufferedReader in
           = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));


    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your Jersey endpoint that should receive the data. You should not need to operate on InputStream when using Jersey with typical JSON messages.

Comment: @R4J Please see my updated question code.

Comment: This will not compile. You are using variable 'in' in the same line as its declaration.

Comment: Yes my typo it is `process`   it is not comiple because I am trying to get it to work with the bufferReader  but How can I get `process`  in? you have already said that  I dont need to operate with the InputStream when using Jersey.

Comment: I thought I have to do it with library like Gson?

Comment: And what is 'process' ? When using Jersey then Jackson will handle all the (de)serialization of Json.

Comment: it should be the InputStream from the Android HttpURlConnection client I dont know hoe to store it into variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jersey you should be able to just declare class Data (with Jackson annotations to support deserialization from JSON):

```
public class Data {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String time;
    private int route;

    @JsonCreator
    public Data(@JsonProperty("latitude") double latitude, 
                @JsonProperty("longitude") double longitude, 
                @JsonProperty("time") String time, 
                @JsonProperty("route") int route) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.time = time;
        this.route = route;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public int getRoute() {
        return route;
    }
}
```

and then define your endpoint as:

```
@Path("/data")
public class Receiver {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {
        // do something with data

        return Response.status(201).build();
    }    
}
```

and it should just work.

Comment: thnaks for your answer. I am just getting `The method status(int) is undefined for the type Response`?

Comment: do I have to include Jackson jar to jersey because I am getting for the these notation `(@JsonProperty` in the data class error like `JsonProperty cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: Yes, you need Jackson JAX-RS Provider: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs / jackson-jaxrs-json-provider on your classpath together with some other Jackson JAR's (but i suppose adding this provider will cause transitive dependencies to be downloaded as well).

Comment: I have added this Jackson provider in my pom.xml  and I can see it with other jar in my maven dependencies but it does not solve the problem `JsonProperty cannot be resolved to a type`?

Comment: Ok the problem it solved after adding `@Provider` to the Data class

Comment: what about this problem `The method status(int) is undefined for the type Response` what does that mean?

Comment: Are you sure you have imported: javax.ws.rs.core.Response and not some other Response type?

Comment: Yes you are right it was something else thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you can modify the client code add this line in your HttpURLConnection connection

```
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

This will convert the input to a POJO

2)If you cannot edit the client HttpUrlConnection the bring in the stream as

```
    @Consumes("{*/*}")
    public Something (String request){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Data data = mapper.readValue(request, Data.class);

        return = getSomething(data);
    }
```